# Dask-Submit not hitting Dask Remote pod

Tags: dask

I'm having issues with dask-submit giving me a 'CommClosedError: Stream is closed' error when trying to run code on the dask-remote pod. I can see the code executes in the dask-scheduler UI but there are no logs for dask-remote. Is there some kind of timeout that happens while using the remote pod?

Comment: show some code and fulltrace